# Read a MPS file

Tags: r, gurobi

Can the gurobi command read() be used from R?
Or there is a way to read a mps file in R, without the need of using packages like Rglpk o linprog?
My idea is to use gurobi from RStudio, but can load the mps files.
Thanks 
Best

Comment: No, I don't think the gurobi R package has any read/write functionality yet. So like you already thought, you will have to use another package for reading the input into R data structures: `linprog::readMps` looks like a good candidate if your problem is a LP. That or use another of the many APIs gurobi has, one that supports read/write (python, c++, etc.)

Comment: True. Is really limited. Python will be my second choice. Best and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since Gurobi version 8.0 (released April 2018), MPS files can be read from within R through the newly added `gurobi_read()` function, see the [full documentation](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/gurobi_read.html).